# Last included javascript file ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot and for some reason the last included plugin is ignored. If I swap their positions the first to last one works but the last one does not. There are no errors in the console to go off of either. If I move the canvasOverlay above the cursor include the overlay works but the cursor options do not and vice versa.

```js
var nfdux021_ram = [["2016-05-19 00:00:01", 21], ["2016-05-19 00:05:02", 21], ["2016-05-19 00:10:01", 21], ["2016-05-19 00:15:01", 21], ["2016-05-19 00:20:01", 20]];
var plot1 = $.jqplot("chart1", [nfdux021_ram], {
  seriesColors: ["rgba(78, 135, 194, 0.7)"],
  title: 'NFDUX021 Memory <?php echo $StartTime . " - " . $FinishTime; ?>',
  highlighter: {
    show: true,
    sizeAdjust: 1,
    tooltipOffset: 9
  },
  grid: {
    background: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.0)',
    drawBorder: false,
    shadow: false,
    gridLineColor: '#666666',
    gridLineWidth: 2
  },
  canvasOverlay: {
    show: true,
    objects: [{
      dashedHorizontalLine: {
        name: 'average',
        y: 25,
        lineWidth: 2,
        color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        shadow: false
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  seriesDefaults: {
    rendererOptions: {
      smooth: true,
      animation: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    showMarker: false
  },
  cursor: {
    show: true,
    showTooltip: false,
    showVerticalLine: true,
    showHorizontalLine: true
  },
  series: [{
    fill: true,
    label: 'Memory',
    highlighter: {
      formatString: 'Memory: %s - %s'
    },
    linePattern: 'line',
    lineWidth: 1

  }, ],

  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
      tickOptions: {
        formatString: "%m-%d %H:%M",
        angle: -90,
        textColor: '#dddddd'
      },
      tickInterval: "4 hours",
      drawMajorGridlines: true
    },
    yaxis: {
      //renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,

      ticks: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
      tickOptions: {
        formatString: "%'d%%",
        showMark: true,
      }
    }
  },


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> -->
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js" </script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js"</script>
```

Comment: You're missing a `>` on your second to last script tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This opening script tag is missing its closing bracket (>)

```
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js" </script>
```

Comment: Thank you been staring at this far to long.